# How to disable ajaxplorer password?

Tags: php, ajax, localserver, pydio

Im using [ajaxplorer](http://www.ajaxplorer.info) on a local server and I dont want to use the user authentication each time I open my browser (write the user and password)

ajaxplorer is created with php and ajax, and I think modifying the source code  is possible to disable the user authentication, or at least use a blank password

but, what lines of the code are necessary to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browse to server/conf and open the file **conf.php**

> ```
> ENABLE_USERS :  Toggle user accounts on/off. If set to 0, the application is not protected!
> ALLOW_GUEST_BROWSING : Toggle whether guests (unauthenticated users) can browse your files.
> ```

http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/documentation-3/chapter-basics/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: can we do this in the new version pydio?